# React/Redux and Websockets for Timer actions

Tags: sockets, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is my use case:

I have two different apps, react client app and express/node backend server app having REST APIs. I want the react client app to refresh the component states, every time the Server sends an event on the socket which has change of the data on the server side.

I have seen examples of websocket doing this (http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/real-time-react-with-socket-io-building-a-pair-programming-app/) but in this case the client and the server components are in the same app. How to do this when you different apps for client and the server components.

Should I use Timer (https://github.com/reactjs/react-timer-mixin) to make a call from the client to the server rest endpoint and refresh the components on the client if there is any change in data. Or does redux middleware provide those capabilities..

thanks, Rajesh

Comment: What stops you from listening to the websocket in some HOC/Aga/Thunk?

Comment: Do you have some examples of how to do it.. I am researching on HOC and thunk now... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is something like react-redux.  This allows you to connect the component to depend on a piece of the state tree and will be updated whenever the state changes (as long as you are applying new references). See below:

**UserListContainer.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as UserActions from '../actions/userActions';
import UserList from '../components/UserList';

class UserListContainer {
  // Subscribe to changes when the component mounts
  componentDidMount() {
    // This function 
    this.props.UserActions.subscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return <UserList {...props} />
  }
}

// Add users to props (this.props.users)
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  users: state.users,
});

// Add actions to props
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
  UserActions
});

// Connect the component so that it has access to the store
// and dispatch functions (Higher order component)
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserListContainer);
```

**UserList.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ users }) => (
  <ul>
    {
      users.map((user) => (
        <li key={user.id}>{user.fullname}</li>
      ));
    }
  </ul>
);
```

**UserActions.js**

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver");

// An action creator that is returns a function to a dispatch is a thunk
// See: redux-thunk
export const subscribe = () => (dispatch) => {
  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (data.type === 'user add') {
      // Dispatch ADD_USER to be caught in the reducer
      dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_USER',
        payload: {
         data.user
        }
      });
    }
    // Other types to change state...
  };
};
```

**Explanation**

Essentially what is happening is that when the container component mounts it will dispatch a `subscribe` action which will then listed for messages from the socket.  When it receives a message it will dispatch another action base off of its type with the corresponding data which will be caught in the reducer and added to state.  *Note:  Do not mutate the state or the component will not reflect the changes when it is connected.

Then we connect the container component using react-redux which applies state and actions to props.  So now any time the `users` state changes it will send it to the container component and down to the UserList component for rendering.

This is a naive approach but I believe it illustrates the solution and gets you on the right track!

Good luck and hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Do you have a short snippet of the server side code, how to receive the event and subscribe on the server side for events dispatched by the clients...

Comment: I can point you in the right direction.  If you look for up socket.io for express there is a ton of tutorials on how to do just that.  Just a quick example is http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/272/how-to-use-socket-io-properly-with-express-framework-in-node-js